# Trix is not working in my Laravel application

Tags: laravel, trix

I'm working on quiz application in Larvel where I need to put some question with style so I was trying to implement [Trix Editor](https://github.com/basecamp/trix) , I put css and js files in app.blade but ***not appearing in view page-source***, here are the screenshots:

**question-create.blade:**

[image]

at the end of question-create.blade I made sections for **css** and **js**:

[image]

and I also *@yield* css and js in **app.blade**:

css:

[image]

js:

[image]

webpage: where I want to use trix:

[image]

and here is view-source: **css**:

[image]

and here is view-source: **js:**

[image]

I refer: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/trix

https://github.com/basecamp/trix

Comment: From where you are getting `<trix-editor>` component?

Comment: Off queation : `@error` directive is display your `{{ $message }}` properly?

Comment: @Muhaddis from github, here is the link https://github.com/basecamp/trix

Comment: @TalhaF. error message Im using if someone tries to submit empty question field, i removed error message property and used only <input> and <trix> but that is also not working.

Comment: New error directive also not working for me. But the old method working as well

Comment: its working on other pages also, but not on question page :-(

Answer (score 0):

Solved, problem was with layout file, Thanks @Muhaddis @TalhaF.